# Failed to start application invoking Workflow Rest API with Cloud SDK libraries

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am following the official documentation to call workflow REST APIs with Cloud SDK libraries.

https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/clients/scp-workflow-rest-api

When I deployed the application to Cloud Foundry environment. It failed to start. The error messages are the same when I started the application locally.

Cloud SDK version: 3.27.0

Below is the error stack.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-28 13:46:44.052 ERROR 23576 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Apache/maven3.6/repository_new/com/sap/cloud/sdk/services/scp-workflow-cf/3.27.0/scp-workflow-cf-3.27.0.jar!/com/sap/cloud/sdk/services/scp/workflow/cf/api/WorkflowInstancesApi.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.boshch.workflow.WorkflowApplication.main(WorkflowApplication.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowInstancesApi.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Souce code

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.boshch.workflow.service.WorkflowDefinitionsService;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpDestination;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.api.WorkflowDefinitionsApi;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.workflow.cf.model.WorkflowDefinition;

@Service
public class WorkflowDefinitionServiceImp implements WorkflowDefinitionsService {

    private static final HttpDestination WF_DESTINATION = DestinationAccessor
                                                            .getDestination("my-workflow-instance")
                                                            .asHttp();
    
    @Override
    public List<WorkflowDefinition> getWorkflowDefinitions() {
        
        List<WorkflowDefinition> wfDefinitions = new WorkflowDefinitionsApi(WF_DESTINATION).queryDefinitions();
        
        return wfDefinitions;
    }

}
```

==============Update=================================================

I narrowed down the root cause of this issue.

I created a fresh project with cloud sdk archetype and added workflow dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>scp-workflow-cf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The application would fail with above error.

Comment: Hi Jerry, please share your relevant source code with us.

Comment: Hi, source code added.

Comment: Hi Jerry, can you quickly confirm the following: You created a fresh project using the scp-cf-spring archetype, added the scp-workflow-cf module and ran `mvn spring-boot:run` and then it fails already? Meaning you did not add any source code? If my understanding is incomplete, please state the precise procedure in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: SAP Cloud SDK 3.28.1 is available since today and fixes this issue.
Check out the release notes [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#fixed-issues).

Thanks for reporting this Jerry. This is a bug, I will update this answer here once a bug fix is released with the SAP Cloud SDK.

As a workaround you can use the Tomee archetype of the SAP Cloud SDK `scp-cf-tomee`. There the problem does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. As a workaround, I will invoke workflow API directly with WebClient interface in Cloud SDK Spring project.

Comment: I added the statement that the latest SAP Cloud SDK version 3.28.1 fixes this issue. Please upgrade and verify that it works Jerry. Thanks again for reporting it.

Comment: Hi Emdee, it works in 3.28.1. I could invoke workflow endpoint successfully. Thank you very much.